# Can we insert multiple values to single attribute of a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Suppose i created a table as shown below:

```
create table blood   
(
 id int(5),
 available_blood text(50),
 constraint pk primary key(id)
 );
```

How can i insert multiple values into available_blood field(i.e., o+,o-,a+,a-....) for a single bank id.

If i have 2 tuples or 2 id's having the available_blood content as follows
id=10, available_blood[a+,a-,o+,o-]
and
id=20, available_blood[a+,b+,b-]

and if i want to fetch the details of id where available_blood='a+'.. i need to get output containing both id's i.e.,

```
select id 
from blood
where available_blood='a+'
```

my output should show both id's now....

My question is how can i insert multiple values into single attribute?

Comment: Then you have multiple records for those `id`. A record for each `available_blood` Storing multiple values in a single field/record is a major database design anti-pattern. If you MUST have a single distinct record for each `id` in this table, then you'll need two tables. The second containing the `id | available_blood` relationship.

Comment: You should learn about entity-relationship design and database normalisation. If you want to store multiple blood types against each "id", then create a second table with columns "blood_type" and "blood_id" where  blood_id is a foreign key to the "id" field in "blood". In the second table the same blood ID can appear multiple times, associated with different blood types. Then you can easily fetch all IDs with a specific blood type using a standard SQL select and JOIN.

Comment: You're asking to violate the [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of
[database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). The short answer is no. The long answer is you create a proper one-to-many relationship structure and populate that, then query with a `JOIN` to get matches.

Comment: Actually, i am getting error while inserting multiple values..So my question is what is the procedure to insert multiple values into single attribute

Comment: "what is the procedure to insert multiple values into single attribute". The correct answer is simply **don't** do it (see everyone's comments above). Re-design your database properly. Otherwise you'll just give yourself problems when you want to retrieve this data later on.